# How to convert an object into a sphere?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, conjectures

I'm not sure if I understand it enough, but doesn't the Poincare conjecture prove any shape can be turned into a sphere? How would I go about transforming such an object? Like let's say I have a rectangular prism with length, width, and height 3,4,5. How would I find the characteristics of the sphere after I create it. This is topology correct? What would I study or look up to understand?

Thanks for any help!

Update:
From the previous comment "A prism is the boundary of a convex subset of R3
R3 so just pick a point on the interior and project along a line from that point onto a sphere which is large enough to enclose the prism. This will define a homeomorphism from the prism to the sphere."

Can someone explain this in more detail?

Comment: "Any shape can be turned into a sphere?" I don't understand what you're suggesting. The Poincaré conjecture says that a certain very small, specific class of spaces is homeomorphic (or diffeomorphic, depending on your choice of conjecture) to $S^n$.

Comment: Try to inflate it...:) Seriously: no, Poincare's Conjecture (now theorem) does not say any shape can be turned into a sphere, but rather that any closed, simply connected manifold in the space is homeomorphic to a sphere.

Comment: When it is explained to the general public, mathematicians have said as long as a shape doesn't have a hole, it can be crumbled into a sphere. There was an article about a rabbit becoming a sphere which I will try to find.

Comment: How would I show that a prism follows the theorem?

Comment: @SethKitchen That rabbit will have to be without holes...as opposed to what usually happens in nature.

Comment: @SethKitchen What about the digestive tract?

Comment: @SethKitchen Can you see a prism is a closed, simply connected 3D object, to begin with?

Comment: @SethKitchen: Lots of articles that try to explain mathematics to the general public are innacurate and down-right *cringeworthy*: take them with a pinch of salt! (Like [this one](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/education/education-news/the-3m-prize-for-maths-welcome-to-the-x2y2-factor-9558043.html), which royally misrepresents the Poincaré Conjecture.)

Comment: Haha @Timbuc that was a joke made by Colbert.

Comment: I'm not sure if the prism exists. I want to check to see if it follows the Poincare Theorem to see if it can exist.

Comment: @SethKitchen Exactly my point: first check what I wrote about the prism.

Comment: A prism is the boundary of a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ so just pick a point on the interior and project along a line from that point onto a sphere which is large enough to enclose the prism. This will define a homeomorphism from the prism to the sphere.

Comment: Do you have any sources I could learn from about "projecting along a line from a point onto a sphere" ?

Comment: I know in R^3 the formula for a sphere is r^2=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$The stereogram shows a rectangular prism being mapped to a larger sphere by radial projection from the center. (The action on the vertices is indicated by dashed lines.)

[image: Stereogram of mapping a rectangular prism to a sphere]

Analytically, center the prism $P$ at the origin, let $R$ denote the radius of the sphere $S$, and let
$$
T(x, y, z) = \frac{R}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}}(x, y, z)
$$
denote radial projection from $\Reals^{3} \setminus\{(0, 0, 0)\}$, the complement of the origin, to the sphere $S$. The mapping $T$ is continuous on its domain, the prism $P$ is a closed, bounded (i.e., compact) subset of $\Reals^{3}$ that does not contain the origin and that intersects each ray from the origin exactly once. It follows that $T$ defines a continuous bijection from $P$ to $S$. Since $P$ is compact, this bijection is a homeomorphism.

Comment: If you have time could you explain how you get this projection and what x,y,z stand for

Comment: $(x, y, z)$ denote Cartesian coordinates. Radial projection away from the origin maps each triple to a proportional triple. To make the image triple lie on the sphere of radius $R$, divide $(x, y, z)$ by its distance to the origin (the square root in the denominator) and multiply by $R$. :)